# PSEXEC: not recognising remote command

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I am able to execute basic operation by triggering batch script on remote location using following command.

```
psexec -e -h -s -u User -p pass \\10.0.0.240 C:\test.bat
```

But when the test.bat file is calling other program specific script like somepy.py then I am getting error on master batch file that these are not internal command. 
Master batch file in Host computer:
***CODE***
   `psexec -e -h -s -u user -p pwd \\10.0.0.240 C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\test.bat`

Command inside `test.bat`located in remote PC:

```
cd C:\Users\Desktop\TEST1
impact -batch test_impact_warp_AP.cmd
`pause`
waitfor /t 5 StartNow
```

`REM wait for 5second`
    `echo "Run python script for Warp"`
   `cd C:\Users\Desktop`
   `call warp-python.bat`

```
ipconfig /all
ping google.com
```

Command inside `warp-python.bat` present in remote machine:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Desktop\Python_Reference 
cd C:\Users\Desktop\Python_Reference\examples\PYTHON_SCRIPT
python t_capture.py
```

1. When I executed the test.bat script directly then `warp-python.bat` as well as `test_impact_warp_AP.cmd` executes perfectly without any error.
2. But when i try to execute test.bat from remote location then `*python*` and `*impact*` commands are not recognised. and gives following error:

   *`'Impact' is not recognised as an internal or external Command`*
   But `ipconfig/all` and `ping` command is executed perfectly in remote PC
3. What am I missing in the command line argument such that psexec in not able to executed the command in remote location

Comment: You might check to see what the environment contains, particularly PATH, on the other machine when running PSEXEC. Powershell can also run remote commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the psexec.exe to your PATH variable in the environment variable or 
   give the full path of psexec.exe in your command.

Example:

```
c:\users\test\Desktop\psexec.exe -e -h -s -u User -p pass \10.0.0.240 C:\test.bat
```

2. Make sure C:\test.bat is present in your remote machine.

Comment: Hi, I tried your step but still psexec is giving ERROR: 'impact' is not recognised as an internal or external command. My setup: test.bat is present in remote machine. This batch file has some Xilinx and python commands. When I run the batch file locally it perfectly executes. I am also able to run psexec to work eg. I can execute ping, ipconfig, cd to remote directory using psexec. But somehow, psexec is giving error while executing commands which are program specific. Am I missing any arguments in the psexec command?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of test.bat

Comment: Inside test.bat ' ipconfig ' 'python -V
 
echo "Running 1st script"
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Python_Reference 
cd C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Python_Reference\examples\TEST
python t_test.py '  . psexec will execute the ipconfig command but fails to recognise python script

Comment: @ user1862493 Inside test.bat    ipconfig    python -V    echo "Running 1st script"    set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Python_Reference     cd C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Python_Reference\examples\TEST    python t_test.py '.    psexec will execute the ipconfig command but fails to recognise python script

Comment: Add your Python directory path to PATH variable in Environment variables in the remote machine. Then execute the same command. It will work. 
Or try like this. `C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Python_Reference\python C:\Users\Desktop\TEST\Python_Reference\examples\TEST\t_test.py` in your psexec command